# Do you have to register your custom validators in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, validation, doctrine, customvalidator

I was reading [the documentation on making custom validators](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) and it doesn't state that you have to register custom created validators, but what else would cause this issue?

I created a custom constraint:

```
namespace Lib\Validators\UniqueValidator\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class Email extends Constraint {

  public $message = "The email entered already exists.";
}
```

and a custom validator:

```
namespace Lib\Validators\UniqueValidator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class EmailValidator extends ConstraintValidator {

  public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint) {
    var_dump($value, $constraint); exit;
  }
}
```

and then when I go to use it:

> ```sh
> The annotation "@\Lib\Validators\UniqueValidator\Constraint\Email" in property  > ImageUploader\Models\User::$email does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
> ```

And I am not sure why. Is there a spelling mistake I can't see? I checked everything 50 times.

In my `bootstrap.php` I have:

```
$loader = require 'vendor/autoload.php';
\Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));
```

But those are for the *symfony* validators, do I have to do something similar for my custom ones? I should also mention I am using [the *symfony* validators component](https://github.com/symfony/Validator) and not full stack *symfony*.

For the view of the directory structure I have done:

[image]

`\Lib` points to the base of `lib/`. I'm sure this isn't standard and it will be fixed soon.

Comment: can you show the mapping of the property email in User entity ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your custom validator must be in the same folder than your constraint. According to your namespaces, it's not the case.

If you want to separate them, you can override the `validatedBy()` method of your `Constraint` class :

```
public function validatedBy()
{
    return get_class($this).'Validator';
}
```